# Product in the category of varieties

Tags: algebraic-geometry, category-theory

I am tasked to show that given affine varieties $X$ and $Y$, that $A(X\times Y)\cong A(X)\otimes A(y)$. I think I am very close I just need a little nudge.

Proof so far

Define the map $\ell:A(X)\times A(Y)\rightarrow A(X)\otimes A(Y)$ by $(f,g)\mapsto f\otimes g$. Also define $\phi:A(X)\times A(Y)\rightarrow A(X\times Y)$ by $(f,g)\mapsto fg$. $\phi$ is clearly a bilinear map. Therefore by universal property there exists a homomorphism $\psi:A(X)\otimes A(Y)\rightarrow A(X\times Y)$, such that $\phi=\psi\circ \ell$. From this I've shown that $\psi$ is onto. I need to show that it is injective. I am looking for a map $\Gamma:A[X\times Y]\rightarrow A(X)\otimes A(Y)$ such that $\Gamma\circ\psi=id$. This would show an injection but. I think the map that I should use is $f(x,y)\mapsto f(x,1)\otimes f(1,y)$. I am stuck actually working with this map though.

Any hint would be great. Thank you.

Comment: Morally, this is true since tensor product is the coproduct in the category of commutative rings.  Can you prove that?

Comment: This question has been asked $\approx 10$ times on math.SE. Use the search function!

Comment: @StevenGubkin No, the tensor product (over what ?) is not the coproduct in the category of commutative rings. However, $B \otimes_A C$ is the coproduct of $B$ and $C$ in the category of $A$-algebras (equivalently, its the pushout of $B$ and $C$ over $A$ in the category of commutative rings).

Comment: @Pece Commutative rings are the same as $\mathbb{Z}-$algebras so the coproduct of two rings is the tensor product over $\mathbb{Z}$.  Another way to phrase this:  a coproduct is the same as a pushout over the initial object, which in this case is $\mathbb{Z}$.  The OP also does not indicate what his coproducts are over, but I think it is safe to assume he also means over $\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: @StevenGubkin Oh yes, sorry. I assumed the OP to work with affine varieties over a (algebraically closed) field. (Hence my hint.) Maybe the OP could make things clearer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint.** Prove that $X \mapsto A(X)$ is an (anti)equivalence of categories from the category of affine varieties to the category of finitely generated reduced $k$-algebras. Your result follows : the antiequivalence $A(-)$ maps coproducts to products.

**Edit.** In my hint, I assumed $k$ to be algebraically closed, so that the tensor product over $k$ is again reduced (by Nullstellensatz). I am not implying that the result is trivial and did not require some strong results. My point is just that you did not need to exhibit an isomorphism.

Comment: Yes, but this only gives you $A(X \times Y) \cong (A(X) \otimes A(Y))/\sqrt{0}$ (the coproduct of reduced $k$-algebras $A,B$ is $A \otimes B / \sqrt{0}$). That the tensor product is already reduced requires some effort (Hilbert's Nullstellensatz etc.) and cannot be obtained by abstract nonsense.

Comment: As already mentioned the proof has been explained a couple of times on math.SE (juse the search function).

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg I was assuming $k$ to be algebraically closed but I forgot to precise it. And I didn't say that it was all abstract non sense, but that we didn't have to exhibit the isomorphism. I'll make an edit to clarify.

Comment: "Your result follows" pretty much says that the claim follows from the anti-equivalence of categories.

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg Yes, once you know that the tensor product over $k$ is reduced. But this requires the Nullstellensatz as you said. I edited so it can not be misleading.

Comment: But TheNumber23 has already constructed a map and couldn't show injectivity. Your answer doesn't explain this injectivity at all (only surjectivity).